# ASP.NET Session state has created a session id, but cannot save

Tags: asp.net, iis

I get error below,

> Session state has created a session id, but cannot save it because the
>   response was already flushed by the application.

But I dont'use Session any where. My application works as API and It doesn't use session State.

And in Web.config

```
 <system.web>
  <sessionState mode="Off"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
```

Why this error going on every request.

I have read that topic. but He uses Session state. but I won't

[What's causing “Session state has created a session id, but cannot save it because the response was already flushed by the application.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904952/whats-causing-session-state-has-created-a-session-id-but-cannot-save-it-becau)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove also the session module on web.config as

```
<httpModules>
  <remove name="Session" />
</httpModules>
```

After that, there is always the possibility some part of your code, or other code that you include to your application, to try to use session -