# Adding Connection: keep-alive header is not returned to client in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, http, server-sent-events, keep-alive, ashx

## Short Version

I'm adding the response header:

```
Connection: keep-alive
```

but it's not in the resposne.

## Long Version

I am trying to add a [header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.headers?view=netframework-4.8) to an [**HttpResponse**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse?view=netframework-4.8) in ASP.net:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    context.Response.AppendHeader("AreTheseWorking", "yes");
    context.Response.Flush();
}
```

And when the response comes back to the client (e.g. Chrome, Edge, Internet Explorer, Postman), the `Connection` header is missing:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
AreTheseWorking: yes
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 26 Feb 2022 16:29:17 GMT
```

What am I doing wrong?

## Bonus Chatter

In addition to trying [**AppendHeader**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.appendheader?view=netframework-4.8):

```
context.Response.AppendHeader("Connection", "keep-alive"); //preferred
```

I also tried [**AddHeader**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.addheader?view=netframework-4.8) *(which exists "for compatibility with earlier versions of ASP")*:

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive"); // legacy
```

I also tried [**Headers.Add**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.headers?view=netframework-4.8):

```
context.Response.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive"); //requires IIS 7 and integrated pipeline
```

What am i doing wrong[?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpprotocol/)

**Bonus:** [hypothetical motivation for the question](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `keep-alive` is not allowed in ASP.net.

In order to allow it, you need to add [an option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpprotocol/) to your `web.config`:

**web.config**:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is especially important for [Server-Send Events:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   if (context.Request.AcceptTypes.Any("text/event-stream".Contains))
   {
      //Startup the HTTP Server Send Event - broadcasting values every 1 second.
      SendSSE(context);
      return;
   }
}
```

```
private void SendSSE(HttpContext context)
{
   //Don't worry about it.
   string sessionId = context.Session.SessionID; //https://stackoverflow.com/a/1966562/12597

   //Setup the response the way SSE needs to be
   context.Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
   context.Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
   context.Response.AppendHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
   context.Response.Flush();

   while (context.Response.IsClientConnected)
   {
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
 
      String data = DateTime.Now.ToString();
      context.Response.Write("data: " + data + "\n\n");
      context.Response.Flush();
   }
}
```